# Python script producing Incorrect Results or AttributeError with NAN Values

Tags: python, nan, attributeerror

I'm trying to scrape a site (discogs.com) for a few different fields (**num_have, num_want, num_versions, num_for_sale, value**) per **release_id**. Generally it works ok, but I want to set some conditions to exclude release ids where:

1. **num_have** is greater than 18,
2. **num_versions** is 2 or less,
3. **num_for_sale** is 5 or less,

So I want results to be any **release id** that meets all three conditions. I can do that for conditions 1 & 2, but the 3rd is giving me trouble. I don't know how to adjust for where **num_for_sale** is 0. According to the api documentation (https://www.discogs.com/developers/#page:marketplace,header:marketplace-release-statistics), the body should look like this:

```
{
  "lowest_price": {
    "currency": "USD",
    "value": 2.09
  },
  "num_for_sale": 26,
  "blocked_from_sale": false
}
```

and "Releases that have no items for sale in the marketplace will return a body with null data in the **lowest_price** and **num_for_sale** keys. Releases that are blocked for sale will also have null data for these keys." So I think my errors are coming from where num_for_sale is 0, the script doesn't know what when value. When I wrap the code that accesses market_data in a try-except block, and set the values for value and currency to None if an exception occurs, I get an AttributeError "NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'"

What am I doing wrong? How should I rewrite this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import time
import tqdm

unique_northAmerica = pd.read_pickle("/Users/EJ/northAmerica_df.pkl")
unique_northAmerica = unique_northAmerica.iloc[1:69]

headers = {'Authorization': 'Discogs key=MY-KEY'}

results = []

for index, row in tqdm.tqdm(unique_northAmerica.iterrows(), total=len(unique_northAmerica)):
    release_id = row['release_id']
    response = requests.get(f'https://api.discogs.com/releases/{release_id}', headers=headers)
    data = response.json()
    if 'community' in data:
        num_have = data['community']['have']
        num_want = data['community']['want']
    else:
        num_have = None
        num_want = None
    if "master_id" in data:
        master_id = data['master_id']
        response = requests.get(f"https://api.discogs.com/masters/{master_id}/versions", headers=headers)
        versions_data = response.json()
        if "versions" in versions_data:
            num_versions = len(versions_data["versions"])
        else:
            num_versions = 1
    else:
        num_versions = 1
    response = requests.get(f'https://api.discogs.com/marketplace/stats/{release_id}', headers=headers)
    market_data = response.json()
    num_for_sale = market_data.get('num_for_sale', None)
    
    # Add the condition to only append to `results` if num_have <= 18 and num_versions <= 2
    if num_have and num_versions and num_have <= 18 and num_versions <= 2:
        if num_for_sale and num_for_sale <= 5:
            if 'lowest_price' in market_data:
                value = market_data['lowest_price'].get('value', None)
            else:
                value = None
        else:
            value = None
        if num_for_sale == 0:
            value = None
        results.append({
            'release_id': release_id,
            'num_have': num_have,
            'num_want': num_want,
            'num_versions': num_versions,
            'num_for_sale': num_for_sale,
            'value': value
        })

    time.sleep(4)

df = pd.DataFrame(results)
df.to_pickle("/Users/EJ/example.pkl")
```

Thanks in advance!

I've tried wrapping the code that accesses market_data in a try-except block, and set the values for value and currency to None if an exception occurs, I get an AttributeError "NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'"

Edit:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [139], line 41
     39 if num_for_sale <= 5:
     40     if 'lowest_price' in market_data:
---> 41         value = market_data['lowest_price'].get('value', None)
     42     else:
     43         value = None

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: Sorry, done an edit to the post now. Thanks ::)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a check to see if the data is None.

```
if 'lowest_price' in market_data and market_data['lowest_price'] is not None:
    value = market_data['lowest_price'].get('value', None)
else:
    value = None
```

In fact you can probably skip checking to see if `lowest_price` exists, because the api instructions tell you it will be there, it just might have null data.

So you could change it to.

```
if market_data['lowest_price']:
    value = ...
else:
    value = None
```

Per the discogs api docs:

> Releases that have no items for sale in the marketplace will return a body with null data in the lowest_price and num_for_sale keys. Releases that are blocked for sale will also have null data for these keys.

Which means that in one of those situations the converted json would look like this:

```
{
  "lowest_price": None,
  "num_for_sale": None,
  "blocked_from_sale": false
}
```

So when your code tries to call `get` on `market_data['lowest_price']` what your actually doing is calling `None.get` which raises the error.

---

The reason why it is still including if `num_for_sale > 5` is because you are appending the results regardless of whether your check returns true of false.  To fix all you need to do is adjust the indentation on your `results.append` statement.

```
    if num_have and num_versions and num_have <= 18 and num_versions <= 2:
        if num_for_sale and num_for_sale <= 5:
            if market_data['lowest_price']:
                value = market_data['lowest_price'].get('value', None)   
            else:
                 value = None
            results.append({
                'release_id': release_id,
                'num_have': num_have,
                'num_want': num_want,
                'num_versions': num_versions,
                'num_for_sale': num_for_sale,
                'value': value
              })
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I try that, the script doesn't exclude any result where num_for_sale is greater than 5. I see that it gives a NAN to values if the first two conditions, but not 3rd, are met. Any ideas? Thanks again!